# Text animation transition

Tags: jquery, html, css, animation, transition

**Here's my [JS FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/gp3puwc2/15/)**

I would like to make the same animation transition on my text (.text) like this website : https://stevenmengin.com/

I don't know how to do the apparition from the bottom with the "cut effect".

How can I do ?

```
.text {
    width: 100%;
    margin: auto;
    text-align: left;
    left: 10%;
    opacity: 0;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: 0px;
    visibility: hidden;
  transition : all 0.5s;
}



.text.active {
    opacity: 1;
  margin-top:-150px;
  width: 100%;
    z-index: 2;
    visibility: visible;
}
```

Comment: I think you need to put your text into a div. This div need to be set to overflow:hidden. Then you can use transform: translateY() to push the text out of its container. That way it will look "cut off"

Comment: I think you can wrap your text with some `<span>` with `overflow: hidden` and set the span height to 0, and during animation change its height to auto or some static value